# Importing specific data from one sheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help moving some data from one sheet to another in Google Sheets. I'm trying to separate one big sheet into smaller, more specific sheets. I have attached a spreadsheet similar to the one I'm using - just using nonsense information instead of the actual data I'm working with.

[image]

If you look at that sheet, you can see I have created a separate sheet at the bottom named after each  individual 'code' (column B) 
What I want to happen is, in say, the jogged sheet, all the data from the first sheet which is in a row with 'jogged' or even 'jogged park' or 'jogged street' in its code is transferred over (so in this example everything highlighted green.) I can't just 'copy' the jogged rows over to the next sheet, because ideally, when someone adds another jogged row to the main sheet, I would like it to automatically transfer over to the jogged sheet.

Then obviously, in the takeaway sheet, the same thing, but for all the rows with takeaway in it.

I'm not great with Sheets, but I can't seem to find any help online for what I'm specifically after and have been struggling with it all day. I can find a lot of information about importing either all the data or specific rows and columns from one sheet to another, but nothing about importing data with key words from one sheet to another. If you need any more clarification, I'll make sure to check this regularly.

Comment: Welcome. Please a add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Try FILTER and QUERY  functions ( there a several questions about then in this site)